# Logic in Science

Tags: logic

I am in the process of writing an essay about how disciplines interlink. In one of my paragraphs I am talking about logic, where is say how logic is a subset of mathemtics (logicism) and therefore any discipline which contains logic therefore interlinks with mathematics.

I am trying to link mathematics with science (logic with science). However I can't seem to think of something where logic is used in science (a particular example).

Anybody have any ideas? or other ways in which maths links with science?

Comment: You have the (simplified) version of logicism backwards.

Comment: mathematics is an extension of logic therefore logic is a subset of mathematics no?

Comment: You cannot apply mathematical theories without using the ordinary rules of logic. Quite apart from mathematics, however, is the implicit logic of cause and effect in science. I say "implicit" because AFAIK the logic of causality has never been adequately formalized. Mathematics does not deal well with cause and effect.

Comment: It is my opinion that math does *not* link with science, only models link with science, in which mathematics is often the language they are made in. This is science using math, not math teaching us anything about science.

Answer (score 0):

Physics is science, but math......also, chemistry requires so much of mathematical calculations, it is also math. And ecology... graphing of populations, calculating increase in birth rate... all is math.... but all of science is not math, and math is not science, even though all of math is used in science

Comment: Why math not is science?